# 'class' attribute for Views in xml file

Tags: android

I was wondering if there is an attribute similar to the `class` attribute in HTML?

I'd like to change some attributes (dimensions and maybe margins) of all the views that are included in this class. So, at the same time change the same attribute for all, instead of going through each View individually by using `findViewById` or some other method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [style resource files](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/style-resource.html) which work very similar to css classes.